# Dota2 crashing from time to time

Tags: technical-issues, dota-2

I am using latest nvidia drivers 334.89 (tried every driver starting from 320) and after patch (approx at the end of november 2013) i am getting sometimes crashes to desktop without any error messages, though i have crash dump:

Can someone tell me, what's wrong here?

My specs is:
Alienware M18x R2 / i7-3820QM / 16gb ram 1866mhz / 2x nVidia gtx 680m SLI / raid 0 Samsung 830 seris ssd 2x256gb

Also i have noticed one strange behavior, when i am using skype latest version (~6) and doing a call during game, skype closes itself very often.

here's the link on mdmp file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5eo1sytfcSPMlpWSlVRVlNCQjA/edit?usp=sharing

Also i am using Norton Internet Security - maybe that's a problem? (When i had no such issus i had kaspersky internet security)

Comment: You're gonna need to provide a bit more info.  When does it happen? What're your system specs?  I had this same problem from a patch around that time as well. Everyone dismissed it as a result of Ember's ult (which it wasn't).  iirc I did eventually find this bug reported, and closed as fixed (and in my case, it went away around..January, I think).  Sadly, waiting might be all you can do.

Comment: Your link does lead to a dead site. please use http://pastebin.com/ instead or if it is a short dump you can post it here too

Comment: I have edited the question, guys! Tell me, if you need some more info, thanks!

Comment: Skype exhibiting the same behavior (is it exactly the same? No error from it either?) leads me to suspect Norton.  Try playing a game or two with it turned off and see what happens?

Comment: Yes, same behavior with skype. I already uninstalled Norton and installed Avast - same results :( i'll try to check my SSD's

Comment: Just checked my SSD's with HD sentinel pro - it found no issues/bad sectors in my SSD. Seriously, what's the hell. Completely reinstalled Steam/Dota2.